# How to take a screenshot from a video capture?

Tags: screenshots

I recorded a screen capture of catching a shiny Pokemon in Pokemon Go and it about 25 seconds long, with the stars sparkling at about 0:00:11 of the video.

So how do I capture the moment and make it into a photo?

---

Details: the Play button is there if I pause it, so it is obstructing the video moment if I take a screenshot at the moment.  I tried all the options or functions available in the Gallery app and then there seems to be no way.

Comment: There a lot of apps in Play Store that allow you to extract frames from a video: https://play.google.com/store/search?q=video%20extract%20frame&c=apps

Answer (score 1):

This web service will help you create a screenshot from a video capture:

https://ezgif.com/video-to-jpg